# Configuration Settings not Working on Frontend for Compare and Wishlist in Magento 2

Tags: frontend, themes, magento2

I am trying to disable the compare and wishlist features attached to a third party theme in Magento 2.  There is a place in settings to do this, but for some reason the changes don't take place on the frontend.

This is what the menu looks like  [image: Wishlist and Compare Menu]
and this is what the frontend looks like.

[image: Frontend Picture]

I already tried clearing the cache and reindexing.  I also know that the theme is compatible with my version of Magento 2, and have not found anything that seems relevent in the error logs.  I have also written to my theme support to ask for help, but I am trying to see if I can solve this quicker on my own.  I am wondering if anyone has any advice for what to do when changing the configuration settings for a theme does not cause a change on the frontend.